# Does the battery have to be rated for the full starting current of a DC motor

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

Do we have to select a battery capable of delivering the full starting current (which is high as it is the stall current) of the DC motor, or is it enough if the battery is rated for a bit more current than the rating of the motor?

Comment: It depends how motor controller is made: if it supplies only rated current, or you have direct connection of DC motor - in this case it will sink max current \$I{start}=\dfrac{U}{R_{winding}}\$.

Comment: Stall current is a function of voltage. This allows you to soft-start the motor at reduced voltage (or reduced PWM duty cycle) provided the reduced stall current generates enough torque to get things moving. Once it's rolling, ramp up to full voltage.

Comment: With small motors that are used without electronic controllers, the internal resistance of the battery and the winding resistance limits the current. The current in the battery may still be more than the rated current, but they are rated to supply higher current for short periods of time. That is why automotive batteries have a "cranking amps" rating.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the load on the motor is. Some loads require high starting torque, a compressor for instance. Some loads require a low or no starting torque, for instance a fan.

Your battery has to - safely - deliver enough current to overcome the starting torque of the load.